# Is it possible in grpc to send message to all subchannels?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

When the grpc channel is created NameResolverFactory and LoadBalancerFactory are assigned to it. In the background Sub-channels are created for each resolved server. Load balancer then balances the queries through sub-channels.

Is it possible to send the message to all the sub-channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. RPCs are not duplicated, in general. Retries are the only case that the an RPC may occur more than once.